# Class property into crystal report fields

Tags: c#, vb.net, crystal-reports

How can I put a class property as a field in my report?

I tried to create a class and property, but it won't show data in the report. Even if I find the class within DataExperts .Net Object's. Am I missing something, or is this just plain impossible to do?

```
Public Class Class

    Public Class Standard
        Public Property Sample As Integer
        Public Property Testing1 As Integer
        Public Property Testing2 As Integer
        Public Property Testing3 As Integer
        Public Property Testing4 As Integer
    End Class
End Class
```

Then I use the properties as database fields in my report:

```
Sample 
Testing1
Testing2
Testing3
Testing4
```

Comment: Wouldnt it be faster to try it rather than post a "I was just wondering..." post?  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: I tried it but i even if i found the class that i want within the .Net Object, its not posting any field within the crystal report.

I tried many times but it doesn't work, so i was wondering if it is really possible, am i just missing something or is it just not possible

Comment: Than you should post *that* code and ask "how....".  The answer to what you have posted is Yes or No and not very helpful to anyone.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]